# appendchild after some specific pixel inside div javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to append a div inside another div after some specific pixel. For example, First, I created a Div than I calculate its Height with `offsetHeight`. Now I want to append a Div Inside parent Div in middle (Half of parents div height)

```js
var ts = document.querySelectorAll('article')[0];
var ks = ts.offsetHeight;
var lirf = ks/2;
```

```html
<article>Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
</article>
```

Want to Append Child at `lirf` px in above code

**Find Answer Close Enough**

When I use absolute position my div overlap other as shown in below code:

```html
<div id='get' style=''>kad</div>
<article >Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
Giving some Height to it.<br/>
</article>
<script>
var ts = document.querySelectorAll('article')[0];
var ks = ts.offsetHeight;
var lirf = ks/2;
var kk = document.getElementById('get');
kk.style.position = "absolute";
kk.style.top=lirf+'px';
</script>
```

Comment: create a `div` with absolute positioning and use `lirf` as top value

Comment: @samuellawrentz can we do it with javascript only ?

Comment: Styling is done with CSS. How you set it doesn't matter, but JavaScript I'd incapable of positioning anything without CSS.

Comment: couldn't we use substr() javascript to find element at thet px and then replace it with our div ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Like I said, styling is only done with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ts = document.querySelectorAll('article')[0];
var ks = ts.offsetHeight;
var lirf = ks/2;


var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top= lirf+'px';
document.querySelectorAll('article')[0].appendChild(div);
```

Hope this helps!

If vertically centering an element is your aim, go through this https://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: top accepts either px or %, we need to append px to the value of `lirf`

Comment: Can You Check Out My  Code above? Due to overlapping i didn't use css